# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm a beginner with Android. I am trying to show a notification at a specific date. When I try to run the method `showNotification()` I get the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver
>   com.example.azernax.dforget.ScheduleNotification:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null
>   object reference

I have tried to fix this error without success.

ScheduleNotification:

```
public class ScheduleNotification extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

private AlarmManager alarmManager;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ScheduleNotification.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

    //create notification to show !!!
    Toast.makeText(context, "TEST schedule!!!! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Notification_center notification = new Notification_center();
    notification.showNotification();  //######################### CRASH !!!!
}
```

Notification_center:

```
public class Notification_center extends AppCompatActivity {

public void showNotification()
{
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    builder.setContentTitle("dF Notification!");
    builder.setContentText("description"); //--description event--

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager NM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NM.notify(0,builder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Notification_center notification = new Notification_center();
```

**NEVER** create an instance of an activity yourself, because it never works properly.

Move the code from `showNotification()` into `onReceive()`. You can use the `Context` passed into `onReceive()` as a replacement for `this` and for the call to `getSystemService()`.

Also, you do not need `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` here. That is for cases where you need to delegate the work to something else (e.g., an `IntentService`). In cases where all the work is completed by the end of `onReceive()`, you do not need to manage a separate `WakeLock`, which is what `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` is for.